# Which is the random variable in a Kalman filter?

Tags: kalman-filter

When estimating a hidden state $x$ with a Kalman filter, there is the posterior and prior estimate. There are also covariances associated with those estimates. Some authors call these the covariances of the *estimates*. How can estimates have covariances when they are expectations of the hidden state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The covariance matrix computed by the Kalman filter is not the covariance matrix of the "estimate."

The Kalman filter is iteratively computing the mean $\bar{\mathbf{x}}_{t|t}$ and the covariance matrix $\mathbf{P}_{t|t}$ of the *marginal posterior distribution* $p(\mathbf{x}_t\,|\,\mathbf{y}_{1:t})$. So conditional on the data, the hidden state at time $t$ is a random variable with a distribution, and the Kalman filter is computing that distribution's mean and covariance matrix.

You can think of the mean $\bar{\mathbf{x}}_{t|t}$ as an "estimate" of the hidden state, but you shouldn't think of the covariance matrix $\mathbf{P}_{t|t}$ as the covariance of the estimate. That is, if you're thinking of $\bar{\mathbf{x}}_{t|t}$ as an *estimator* for $\mathbf{x}_t$, it will have a sampling distribution with respect to the randomly sampled data $\mathbf{y}_{1:T}$. But $\mathbf{P}_{t|t}$ is *not* the covariance matrix of that sampling distribution.